# загрузка фото в телеграмм бота и сохранение данных в БД

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Столкнулся с такой дилемой. Хочу в бота закинуть несколько изображений и записать их id и название в sqlite, но не понимаю, как мне вытащить название файла. Сейчас делаю так

```
async def handle_photo(message: types.Message):
      id_photo = message.photo[-1].file_id


dp.message.register(handle_photo, content_types=['photo'])
```

кидаю фото в чат и переменную id_photo пишу в БД. Не пойму как туда добавить ещё и название, а то я же потом ни за что не разберусь что у меня за фото под этими номерами...
P.S. Конечно я потом добавлю правила что в БД могу писать только я, а другие отправленные фото будут обрабатываться по другому. Сейчас ключевой вопрос как с названием поступить?

UPDATE
Поступил отличный совет, но как его реализовать пока не понимаю. В название фото записывать текст который отправляется вместе с фото. Как этот текст вытащить
попробовал так

```
async def handle_photo(message: types.Message):
    id_photo = message.photo[-1].file_id
    print(id_photo)
    name_photo = message.text
    print(name_photo)
```

но переменная name_photo пустая.

Comment: ты хочешь сохранить то название фото, под которым его отправляет пользователь?

Comment: @Dmitry В идеале да. По какой то логике у видео, аудио и документов есть опция file_name, а у фото и стикеров нету. А мне надо бы как то идентифицировать загруженные фото или придётся сходу их везде вставлять, а я могу что то пропустить, да и не удобно это. Ну и все фото которые надо сохранить буду отправлять я сам

Comment: В таком случае можно указывать в тексте сообщения название фото :) из файл_айди можно извлечь еще некие данные (подробнее [тут](https://github.com/danog/tg-file-decoder)), но того, что вам надо, там нет :(

Comment: @Dmitry Точно! Не подумал о том, что вместе с фото можно и текст отправлять! Я думаю это будет лучшим вариантом для меня. Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Я не Ванга, не знаю какая у вас там ошибка появляется.

Comment: @Dmitry Нет ошибки, переменная пустая и всё

Answer (score 0):

Всё, нашел решение.

```
async def handle_photo(message: types.Message):
    id_photo = message.photo[-1].file_id
    name_photo =  message.caption
```

И буду писать в базу подпись к фото как имя файла. Спасибо за помощь [dmitry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/471375/dmitry)